# when a SelectionKey turns writable in java nio

Tags: java, nio

Now my server reads all the message from client. Now it is a one way communication. I want to  send message to client by the server. Now server reads message when the key is READABLE STATE it didnt turn to writable state i just want to know when the key changes to writable.

Comment: The key itself won't change to writable, you need to register your interest in the writable action like you did for the read action when there is data there is data that should be written. Then selector.select() will give you a key that will be writable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);`

Comment: No. This is what *enables* it to become writable. It *becomes* writable when there is room in the socket send buffer.

Answer (score 5):

> i just want to know when the key changes to writable

It is almost always writable. `OP_WRITE` is triggered whenever there is free space in the socket send buffer, which is almost all the time. Just call `write(),` and if you get a zero return *then* you start getting interested in `OP_WRITE`: you use it to tell you when the channel has become writable again.

But you don't need to wait for this event, *unless* you have just had a zero-length return from `write().` In the normal case you should just write when ready, and only have `OP_WRITE` registered in the intervals between when `write()` returns zero and when it doesn't after you retry having registered `OP_WRITE` and had it fire.